# JS/jQuery Local Storage array

Tags: javascript, jquery, stringify

Currently I have this multiple button with `data-id` and `data-name`

Here's my idea and sample code

```js
$(".clickCompare").click(function ({
      var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var name = $(this).attr('data-name');           

      var datas = [id , name];
      localStorage["datas"] = JSON.stringify(datas);
      var stored_datas = JSON.parse(localStorage["datas"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="clickCompare btn btn-primary" data-id="1" data-name="Sample1">Compare</button>
<button type="button" class="clickCompare btn btn-primary" data-id="2" data-name="Sample2">Compare</button>
<button type="button" class="clickCompare btn btn-primary" data-id="3" data-name="Sample3">Compare</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is to store the `data-id` and `data-name` on variable `datas` every click of `clickCompare` class. So that I can call them whenever I want.

And if the ID already exists it will not store on variable `datas`

Comment: Is there an error?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to save an array of objects (tuple).
In this case datas should be something like

```
let datas = [{id: 1, name: 'first'}, {id: 2, name: 'second'}];
```

so each time you click you can add a new item in the array.
To do that, you can check if there's an item in the array with that id.
Use a function like this

```
$(".clickCompare").click(() =>{
    let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let name = $(this).attr('data-name');  
    let datas = [];

    if(localStorage.key('datas')){
        datas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('datas'));
    }

    if(!datas.filter(x => x.id == id)){
        datas.push({id: id, name: name});
    }

    localStorage.setItem('datas', JSON.stringify(datas));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('datas')); //to remvoe after testing
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create key value pair instead of array as below -

```js
$(".clickCompare").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var stored_datas = localStorage["datas"];
  if (!stored_datas) {
    stored_datas = "{}";
  }
  var datas = JSON.parse(stored_datas);
  var existingData = datas[id];
  if (existingData) {
    console.log(`Data for id ${id} already exists - ${existingData}`);
    return;
  }
  var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
  datas[id] = name;
  var json = JSON.stringify(datas);
  localStorage["datas"] = json;
  console.log(`Added new data for id ${id}  - ${name}`);
  var stored_datas = JSON.parse(localStorage["datas"]);
  console.log(`Local Storage content - ${json}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="clickCompare btn btn-primary" data-id="1" data-name="Sample1">Compare</button>
<button type="button" class="clickCompare btn btn-primary" data-id="2" data-name="Sample2">Compare</button>
<button type="button" class="clickCompare btn btn-primary" data-id="3" data-name="Sample3">Compare</button>
```

Since stackoverflow disables localStorage for snippets, refer [link](https://jsfiddle.net/f80wvkoh/) for demo

Comment: the output should be something like this `{id: 1, name: 'first'}, {id: 2, name: 'second'}` right

Comment: No it will store it like - {"1": "Sample1","2":"Sample2","3":"Sample3"}, but you can also do it the way you mentioned, by changing some code.